# Two particle scattering amplitudes for Schroedinger Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

I am interested in calculating the scattering amplitudes of two particles interaction, like an electron and hole is scattering. I am interested in non relativistic approach to find this amplitude rather than relativistic amplitudes. I need a detailed discussion or lecture. Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: You can find the relativistic amplitude and take the non-relativistic limit.

Comment: Also, see Chapter 5 of Quantum Field Theory textbook by Peskin and Schroeder.